# Is my proof that b(x,y) = <Bx,y>, using bilinearity, correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, inner-products, bilinear-form

Show that for a bilinear skew-symmetric function, mapping $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$,

$b(x,y)=\langle Bx,y\rangle$, where $\langle x,y\rangle$ is the inner product $\sum_j x_jy_j$.

My work:

Define the matrix B with entries $B_{ij}$ = $b(e_i,e_j)$

Using the standard basis for $R^n$, write $\vec x = \sum_i x_ie_i$ and $\vec y=\sum_j y_je_j.$

Then we have that

$$b(\vec x,\vec y) = b\big(\sum_i x_ie_i,\sum_j y_je_j\big)$$
$$= \big(\sum_i \sum_jb(x_ie_i, y_je_j)\big)$$
$$= \big(\sum_i \sum_jx_iy_jb(e_i, e_j)\big)$$
$$= \big(\sum_i \sum_jx_iy_jB_{ij}\big)$$
$$= \big(\sum_ix_i \sum_jy_jB_{ij}\big)$$
$$= \big(\sum_ix_i \sum_jB_{ij}y_j\big)$$
$$= \big(\sum_ix_i \langle B_i,\vec y\rangle \big)$$
$$= \big(\sum_i \langle B_ix_i,\vec y\rangle \big)$$
$$=  \langle B\vec x,\vec y\rangle,$$
as required.

I am not so sure about the **last 3 equalities**, going from rows $B_i$ to the whole matrix $B$ seems a little awkward -- but the logic seems fine to me, using just bilinearity and the inner product definition.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Standard notation is $\langle B\vec{x},\vec{y}\rangle$, not $<B\vec{x},\vec{y}>$.  And $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$, not $\mathbb R^n x \mathbb R^n$.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I guess it is not a matter of notation but rather of TeX usage, which the OP might be lacking.

Comment: ...what do you think of my last 3 equalities, @PedroTamaroff :-)

Comment: It should give you some pause that you haven't made any use of the skew-symmetry of $b$.

Comment: Hi @PaulSinclair, I proved that as an aside:  $B_{ij} = b(e_i, e_j) = -b(e_j,e_i)= -B_{ji}$, showing the skew-symmetry of the matrix, $B$.  But I don't see how the skew-symmetric function $b$ needs to be used...

Comment: Well I admit in my own investigation, I get the same. Maybe your source is only needing this for skew-symmetric function, and therefore tosses in the condition without bothering on whether it's necessary? Your logic is correct, but it is rather unclear to follow at this point. I would look at rewriting it. Perhaps without involving the $B_i$ vectors? Perhaps start with $\langle B\vec x, \vec y\rangle$, break out the vectors in terms of the basis $e_i$, and work back to $b(\vec x, \vec y)$ (at one point you will need to use $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Hi @PaulSinclair, thanks for your suggestions; I did rewrite it and came across something tricky, which if I resolve, then my proof is done.  The problem is: what is $<Be_i,e_j>$?  It apparently is $b(e_i,e_j)$, which is exactly what I need to come out to finish my proof, but I feel that it's actually $b(e_j,e_i)$.  If you look at the inner product, the first argument reads off the $i^{th}$ column of B; then,taking the inner product of this column against $e_j$ should read off the $j^{th}$ row of this column vector.  So, the result is $[B]_{ji}$, which is opposite of what I need, unfortunately

Comment: What do you think?  Thanks @PaulSinclair,

Comment: I started the proof with $B<\vec x, \vec y> = ... $, just as you suggested, which was nice, because then there were no ambiguous $B_i$ vectors that showed up ... @PaulSinclair

Comment: Define $B$ to be the matrix with entries $[B]_{ij} = b(e_j. e_i)$. As I understand the problem, you are just trying to find a $B$ for which this holds, not a specific form.

Comment: Ok got it - thanks so much for your help @PaulSinclair.  Have a great night and talk soon :-)

Comment: Hi @PaulSinclair, I am sort of itching to ask this last question, so I might as well :-)  I know that it's standard technique to start with $\vec x = \sum x_i e_i$ and $\vec y = \sum y_j e_j$.  But, why can't we use the same dummy variable as the one used for $\vec v$ so that $\vec y = \sum y_i e_i$?  Do these types of summation proofs fall apart?  I'm thinking that we should be able to use the same dummy variable, because we are expressing both vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ in the **same** canonical basis.  Or, am I missing the point about some other issue, possibly?  Thanks so much,

Comment: It is true that $\vec y = \sum y_ie_i$, but when you combine them you need two indices to keep track of all the terms. For example, if we choose a basis $\{v_i\}$ which is not orthonormal, and $x = \sum_i \hat x_iv_i, y = \sum_i \hat y_iv_i$, then $\langle \vec x, \vec y\rangle = \sum_i \sum_j \hat x_i \hat y_j \langle v_i, v_j\rangle$. Without two separate indices, you would not pick up all the combinations. (With orthonormal $\{e_i\}$, all but the diagonals are $0$, so you can get away with only one index for it.) The same is in this problem: $B_{ij} \ne B_{ii}$.You need 2 indices.